# How to find location within list?

Tags: python

I suspect this is a basic question(but I tried to google and search SO with no luck).

I have a list: `[1, 2,3,4]`

and I want to know where in the list the value of 3 is..but without using a for loop to go through the entire list.  Is that possible?  I'm already going through a very large list and want to minimize the number of loops through the entire list.

Is this possible?

Comment: omg thank you very much Jeff.  Its so simple but I didn't use it before.  I've been using for loops to find locations..Thank you so much..

Comment: Maybe you could be interested to learn the existence of the function ``enumerate()``

Comment: Thanks Eyquem.  I knew about it, and am using it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].index(3) # --> 2
```

`.index()` will raise an IndexError if it cannot find the value you are looking for.

Keep in mind if you are doing lots of `.index()` look-ups on large lists, that it can be *very* slow -- Python has to brute-force loop through the lists just like you were doing.

Comment: Interesting thank you. I am sure the variable I am looking for exists in the loop(I am getting the value from a for loop going through the same list), but didn't want to go through the entire list again to do another look. Performance wise, would it be better to use tuples then? Or another idea was if I keep track of the loop going forward, say I'm on variable 8 out of 10 of the list, then I can just subtract the 8 from 10, and 2 is probably where that same variable is located on the reversed list?

Comment: @Lostsoul, tuples suffer from the same problem.  Why are you having to look again?  Can you swap the `for` loop for an `index` look-up?  While it can be slow if you do **many** index look-ups, it is still much faster than using a for loop.

Comment: But note that a list like `[1,2,3,4]` doesn't have `.find()`.

Comment: Thanks -- I was confusing lists with strings.  Fixed answer.

Comment: @EthanFurman I try to reduce the number of for loops, which is why I was trying to figure out an easier way. If indexof is doing something simliar than what I'm doing I may not use it(I will have several thousand values in the list).  Since i'm going through the list in order(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) then going backwards on specific triggers(8,7,6,5...) I think I might use enumerate to keep track of where I am, then reverse the entire list and do a "len(dataList) - counter" to figure out the starting point of the new reversed list.

Comment: It's doing the same thing, but 100 times faster* because its built-in.  *okay, I don't know exact speed-up, but it's huge.  Check out the timeit module if you want exact measurements.

Comment: Thanks Ethan.  I'll give it shot. Thank you so much for helping me figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

This really is a very basic question. You should look up the docs, e.g. here: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange

So your solution is:

```
[1,2,3,4].index(3)
# 2
```

Where 2 is the index, so:

```
[1,2,3,4][2]
# 3
```